# Not able to install node-v16.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz in Ubuntu using tar

Tags: tar

```
:/usr/local$ tar --strip-components 1 -xzf /home/pallavi/node-v16.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar: README.md: Cannot open: File exists
tar: LICENSE: Cannot open: File exists
tar: CHANGELOG.md: Cannot open: File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Why I am not able to install node-v16.2.0-linux-x64.tar.gz?

Comment: What is your question ? Have you checked if those files exists ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use non-optimal method of Node.js installation. The developer [provides deb-repository](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) with deb-packages.

To install using deb-packages use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```